# What is the correct way to specify type for a React Navigation drawer in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm confused about how to explicitly type my [Drawer Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator) in my TypeScript code.

I can easily get things to behave as I expect, for example, in the following code. In particular the drawer-specific methods (e.g., `openDrawer`, etc.) all works as they should. But my linter complains that none of those methods are defined with

> TS2339: Property 'openDrawer' does not exist on type 'NavigationProp { key: string; index: number; routeNames: never[]; history?: unknown[] | undefined; routes: NavigationRoute []; type: string; stale: false; }>, {}, {}>'.

I can move this problem around with tricks like replacing

```js
 const navigation = useNavigation()
```

with

```js
 const navigation: Drawer = useNavigation()
```

but always get some sort of error (here "TS2304: Cannot find name 'Drawer'."). And can eliminate the error by guessing

```js
 const navigation: Drawer.DrawerNavigationProp<any> = useNavigation()
```

But I've lost track of what is going on there.

What is the correct way to specify that `navigation` is a navigation drawer (I'm not even sure of the correct type to specify)?

---

NavigationExample.tsx:

```js
import React, { ReactElement }  from 'react'
import {useNavigation} from "@react-navigation/native"

const NavigationExample = (): ReactElement => {
    const navigation = useNavigation()

    return (
        <View style={ styles.container }>
            <Text style={ styles.testText }>Navigation</Text>
            <Button onPress={ () => navigation.toggleDrawer() } title="Toggle" color="blue" />
            <Button onPress={ () => navigation.openDrawer() } title="Open" color="green" />
            <Button onPress={ () => navigation.closeDrawer() } title="Close" color="red" />
        </View>
    )
}
```

App.tsx:

```js
import NavigationExample from './components/NavigationExample'
//...

import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'

export const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()

const App = () =>  {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Navigation" component={ NavigationExample } />
          // ...
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the *'correct'* way to do it but here is how we have used it in some projects:

```js
import { 
  NavigationContainer, 
  useNavigation, 
  NavigationProp, 
  ParamListBase 
} from "@react-navigation/native"
import { 
  createDrawerNavigator, 
  DrawerNavigationProp 
} from "@react-navigation/drawer";

/* ... */

const navigation = useNavigation<DrawerNavigationProp<ParamListBase>>()
```

Comment: How does one discover what works (and which of the many things that work are the right way)? The navigation documentation seems to be totally unconcerned with TypeScript — or with anything having to do with types for that matter.

Comment: I got some orientation at this site https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/ . It also mentions the `DrawerNavigationProp`

Comment: It feels like there's still a lot of guessing involved, but the linked docs help in the basic case for defining some components. That link should be part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, `openDrawer(), closeDrawer(), toggleDrawer()` are not property of usenavigation hook. You can achive it using dispatch. Have a look on the code bellow:

```
import { useNavigation, DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

Load navigation at the top of the component or screen.

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

Inside your function

```
navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
```